# Using the normalizer to reduce a recursive function

Tags: fstar

I want to prove a property parameterized over a finite number of cases. I would like to divide the problem to one instance per case and solve each instance separately. Here is an example to clear up things:

```
module Minimal
open FStar.List
open FStar.Tactics
open FStar.Reflection.Data

unfold let lst = [0;1]

unfold let prop i = 
  match i with
  | 0 -> i == 0
  | 1 -> i == 1
  | _ -> False

val propHolds (i:int) : Lemma (requires (List.mem i lst)) (ensures (prop i))
```

In this case the cases are defined by the list lst.
I can easily prove propHolds:

```
let propHolds i =
  assert_by_tactic (prop 0) (fun () -> norm[delta;primops;iota;zeta]; dump "normalized"; trivial ());
  assert_by_tactic (prop 1) (fun () -> norm[delta;primops;iota;zeta]; dump "normalized"; trivial ())
```

but I obviously don't want to write a separate assert_by_tactic for each case (not when there may be thousands..).
I somehow want to generate the proof above automatically for all elements in lst.

I tried various things, here is one of them:

```
  assert_by_tactic (let rec props i =
                       if i = 0 then prop 0
                       else (prop i) /\ (props (i-1))
                    in
                      props 1) (fun () -> norm[delta;primops;iota;zeta]; dump "normalized")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite achieve what I would like, the assert_by_tactic fails (and is not reduced in the way I would expect). I think I am missing something obvious about normalization, but what is the canonical way to do this in F*? Bonus points if the solution points to the "case"/assertion that failed if there exists one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F*'s type system only ensures weak normalization of terms. Well-typed open terms can diverge, e.g., when reduced in an inconsistent context. To guard against this, the F* normalizer employs various heuristics and, by default, conservatively refuses to reduce recursive calls in the bodies of unreduced matches. This is what prevents List.mem from reducing fully to a cascade of unreduced if/then/else's (if/then/else is just sugar for a match on a Boolean).

`List.memP`, a related function from F*'s standard library is more reduction friendly in this case, since it does not block on unreduced matches internally. Note, List.memP need not always be more reduction friendly than List.mem---the latter is Boolean, so it can in some cases compute more (e.g., `List.mem 3 [1;2;3]` will reduce just fine to `true`);

Try this program:

```
module Minimal
open FStar.Tactics

let lst = [0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]

let prop i =
  match i with
  | 0 -> i == 0
  | 1 -> i == 1
  | 2 -> i == 2
  | 3 -> i == 3
  | 4 -> i == 4
  | 5 -> i == 5
  | 6 -> i == 6
  | 7 -> i == 7
  | 8 -> i == 8
  | 9 -> i == 9
  | 10 -> i == 10
  | _ -> False

let propHolds (i:int) =
  assert (List.memP i lst ==> prop i) 
      by (dump "A";
          norm [delta_only [`%List.memP; `%lst]; iota; zeta; simplify];
          dump "B")
```

At `dump B`, you'll see the hypothesis reduced to a nested disjunction. Z3 can prove the goal easily from there.

Here's another way to do it, this time without tactics.

```
let trigger_norm (a:Type) 
  : Lemma
    (requires a)
    (ensures (Pervasives.norm [delta_only [`%List.memP; `%lst]; iota; zeta; simplify] a))
  = ()


let propHolds (i:int) 
  : Lemma
    (requires List.memP i lst)
    (ensures prop i)
  = trigger_norm (List.memP i lst)
```

Now, in response to jebus' comment below, you can go further and prove the postcondition using a tactic, although, the SMT solver is really pretty fast at doing this … so I wouldn't use a tactic for this unless you had some specific strong reason for doing so.

Here's one more solution:

```
module SO
open FStar.Tactics

let lst = [0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]

let pred i =
  match i with
  | 0 -> i == 0
  | 1 -> i == 1
  | 2 -> i == 2
  | 3 -> i == 3
  | 4 -> i == 4
  | 5 -> i == 5
  | 6 -> i == 6
  | 7 -> i == 7
  | 8 -> i == 8
  | 9 -> i == 9
  | 10 -> i == 10
  | _ -> False

let case_impl (a b c:Type) 
  : Lemma
    (requires (a ==> c) /\ (b ==> c))
    (ensures (a \/ b) ==> c) 
  = ()

let solve_pred_impl () : Tac unit =
    let eq = implies_intro () in
    rewrite eq;
    norm [delta_only [`%pred]; iota];
    trivial()

let test i =  
  assert (List.memP i lst ==> pred i)
      by (norm [delta_only [`%List.memP; `%lst]; iota; zeta; simplify];
          let _ = repeat 
            (fun () ->
              mapply (`case_impl); 
              split();
              solve_pred_impl()) in
          solve_pred_impl())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Nik. However, this still isn't quite the same as my first solution which manually "unrolled" prop.
`assert_by_tactic (prop 0) (fun () -> norm[delta;primops;iota;zeta]; dump   "normalized"; trivial ())`
This will apply 0 to prop and normalize the expression i == 0 reducing it to 0 == 0 which you can easily discharge (basically you shouldn't even need the SMT in this case). So what I am looking for is an automatic way to do this; Simplify prop, reducing it for each possible (valid) argument and then prove each of these with or without the SMT solver.

Comment: There are two parts to doing this proof. The first is to invert `List.memP i lst` (by normalizing it) and then to prove `prop i` for each (and only those) case that arises. I have edited my answer to show how you can do this with a tactic.

Comment: I understand that the normalization routine used for type-checking can't loop, but there is no such constraint for tactics. For tactics looping is just fine. Would the NBE-based normalizer be able to eventually reduce this properly?

Comment: hi Catalin, `List.mem i lst ==> pred i` cannot be proven by normalization alone, regardless of the reduction strategy used. You have to normalize the LHS, invert the cases, rewrite the RHS for each case, and normalize it. That's pretty much what my last solution does, except using `memP` instead of `mem`. Do you mean that you would like this to work with `mem` as well? If so, yes, that can be done, but requires a little bit of work on the implementation to tweak those loop-detection heuristics, or use NBE or something.